# I can't import cairocffi module

Tags: python, cairo, pycairo

I am trying to import the cairocffi module. However, when doing so, the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dante\Desktop\modules\MODULOS TERMINADOS\winprint_cairo\winprint.py", line 10, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    cairo = dlopen(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 45, in dlopen
    raise OSError(error_message)  # pragma: no cover
OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found
no library called "cairo" was found
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e
```

I quote [the documentation](https://cairocffi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#installing-cairo-on-windows)

> cairocffi needs a libcairo-2.dll file in a directory that is listed in
> the PATH environment variable.
>
> Alexander Shaduri’s GTK+ installer works. (Make sure to leave the Set
> up PATH environment variable checkbox checked.) Pycairo on Windows is
> sometimes compiled statically against cairo and may not provide a .dll
> file that cairocffi can use.

Following the documentation, I downloaded the dll and put it in the system32 and python folder, but still can't find it.

What am I doing wrong? What step am I forgetting?

And if someone wants to answer me one more question... Would it be possible to load the dll from the folder of my module?

I have Python 3.9 32 bit on a 64 bit windows.

Comment: @harrysrangal Thanks for the tags. However, my question has nothing to do with pycairo that I know of, if not of a replacement.